# How do I iterate over a `page` object's properties in a template?

Tags: wagtail

I have a Django template page that looks something like this.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags static %}
{% block body_class %}template-bidpage{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% for prp in page %}
        <p>{{ prp }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

But loading this page up gives me the error `'MyPage' object is not iterable`. How do I display each proeprty of my `MyPage` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a method inside your model class to return the properties.

```
class MyPage(Page):

    # your fields go here

    def get_properties(self):
        # return all properties
```

Then in your templates

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags static %}
{% block body_class %}template-bidpage{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% for prp in page.get_properties %}
        <p>{{ prp }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```